# Launching multiple VS code editor on ubuntu 18.04 crashes the Reactjs code

Tags: 18.04, visual-studio-code

**Ubuntu 18.04, Visual studio code 1.23.1, React JS programming**

When i launch 2 instances of VS code and try to run my Reactjs code on any one instance, ReactJS code crashes immediately. This never happened before a week or so. I think, recent security update has some limits on RAM buffer size. But i can launch and run many Reactjs codes(tried 4) simultaneously from the stand alone terminal (yarn start) smoothly.

At the moment i am continuing my development with Centos 7. I launched 4 instances of VS code and could run different Reactjs codes smoothly. I can monitor the RAM on Conky and it doesn't exceed 3.5GB with 4 instances of VS code. But on Ubuntu, even with one instance of VS code, it crosses 2GB from less than 1GB. Not sure, why Ubuntu eats so much memory?.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

```
yarn run v1.6.0
(node:16863) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues.   
 Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

**Temporary solution:**

Run this once every time you launch VScode.

```
yarn add buffer-from --save
```